# Waiting with $(document).ready, $(element).ready, and windows.load all trigger before content is ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

Would you please help me delay execution of my function until the content has loaded?  I've streamlined my code to the essentials, bear with my typos:

```html
function Phase1()
{
 $(".Hidden").load("hidden.html");
 $(window).load(Phase2());

/* I've also tried $(document).ready(Phase2()); */
/* and $(."Hidden").load("hidden.html",Phase2()); */
/* and window.onload... */

}
 
function Phase2()
{
    var Loop;
    var Source_Array = document.getElementsByClassName("Random");
    for (Loop=0;Loop<Source_Array.length,Loop++)
    { alert(Source_Array[Loop].innerHTML; };
}
```

The Random class contains several items.  On the first pass the alerts are never called (length is 0), on the 2nd iteration it's had time to load everything.

I see no errors in the console when executing.

Comment: `$(document).ready(Phase2)` -- pass the function as an argument, don't call it!

Comment: Thanks!  That did the trick.  Where's that head smacking emoji...

I replaced Phase2() with Phase2.

Answer (score 0):

I have a small and neat solution for your problem, all you need to do is,

Call a setInterval for very short span to check the element is present in DOM or not, if its not your interval will go on, once the element is present, trigger your functions and clear that interval.

code will look like this..

```
 var storeTimeInterval = setInterval(function() {
     if (jQuery('.yourClass').length > 0) {
       //do your stuff here..... and then clear the interval in next line
       clearInterval(storeTimeInterval);
     }
  }, 100);
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, this is perfect for achieving persistence.

Answer (score 0):

The page will load the elements from top to bottom.

If you want your JS code to execute after all elements have loaded, you may try any of the following:

1. Move your script to the bottom of the page.

```html
<html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
          <!-- Your HTML elements here -->
          <script>
            // Declaring your functions
            function Phase1()
            {
              $(".Hidden").load("hidden.html");

            }
 
            function Phase2()
            {
                var Loop;
                var Source_Array = document.getElementsByClassName("Random");
                for (Loop=0;Loop<Source_Array.length,Loop++)
                { alert(Source_Array[Loop].innerHTML; };
            }
            
            // Executing your functions in that order.
            Phase1();
            Phase2();
          </script>
      </body>
  </html>
```

2. Bind your functions to document ready using Vanilla JS.

   ```
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
       Phase1();
       Phase2();
   });
   ```
3. Bind your functions to document using jQuery.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       Phase1();
       Phase2();
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and explaining how to use the Event Listener!